# Implement CRUD for entity with foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement a little app with simple CRUD operations in ASP.NET MVC4 with Entity Framework. How I should implement it for this entity:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual Role UserRole { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Should I make another model like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

and use it for Add and Edit views? Or there is the better way for it? Can I use UserProfile class for these views?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to create one class to implement CRUD. 
In your controllers (or for a better abstraction, in a services layer) you call your DbContext to add, edit, delete or select your entities.

Take a look here:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Here is a simple example to add a movie which has a category:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateMovie(string Title, string Category)
    {
        Movie m = new Movie();
        m.Title = Title;

        if (Category != "" && Category != null)
        {
            m.Category = _context.Categorys.First(c => c.Id == Int32.Parse(Category));
        }

        _context.Movies.Add(m);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```